# Some website images are not showing in the webview of the android

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to load a website(***http://www.mdzaika.com/***) through the webview of Android. But some of the images are not displayed in the webview.

The issue I have seen on a particular website, I have tried to a different website, this issue has not been seen.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

...

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mdzaika_layout);
browser = findViewById(R.id.webview);
splashImage = findViewById(R.id.splashScreen);
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
browser.setWebViewClient(new MDZaikaBrowser());
WebSettings webSettings=browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

browser.loadUrl("http://www.mdzaika.com/");
}
```

MDZaikaBrowser.java

```
private class MDZaikaBrowser extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    Log.d(TAG, "progress bar Visible. Url = " + url);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return true;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    splashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    browser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_internet_error_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (splashImage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        finish();
    else
        view.loadUrl("about:blank");
}


}
}
```

I am expecting to display all the images as shown in the mobile browser.
But some of the images are not displayed properly.

Comment: what is your testing device ?

Comment: Hi, My testing device is Samsung A6+

Comment: Which images aren't loading?

Comment: The image in the link is my output. You can be seen in the top right corner. I have made a red circle.          https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4CAF.jpg

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Baba, Recently me faced the same,that's an issue with website may be some plugins won't allow webview to display so you need to change the plugin. thank u

Comment: @Varma. Thank you for the information. I also feel that there is some issue on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same issue using Chrome inspect:

[image]

And looking at the CSS it is setting that content to a unicode character `f103`:

[image]
which is a box:

https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=f101

So yeah, go checkout the website CSS files for why that is.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what is the problem , but i'm sure it's not coming from you , i tested the website on my chrome in laptop and pressed **F12** button, and open device toolbar , the website is shown as the picture you mentioned in all devices , try it yourself !

so i i'm pretty sure the problem is coming from the website !

[image]